# Hibernate ans oracle stored procedures

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have an oracle stored procedure :`

---

```
    create or replace procedure getClientFromAuthentification(myCursorResult out sys_refcursor, login in VARCHAR2, pwd in VARCHAR2) as
num_client NUMBER(6);

compte_epargne VARCHAR2(50);

compte_courant VARCHAR2(50);

nom VARCHAR2(50);

prenom VARCHAR2(50);

adresse VARCHAR2(100);

begin

  open myCursorResult for

    select client.num_client, client.num_compte_epargne, client.num_compte_courant, 
client.nom_client, client.prenom_client, client.adresse_client

    from client 

    where client.login_client = login and client.mdp_client = pwd;

  fetch myCursorResult into num_client, compte_epargne, compte_courant, nom, prenom, adresse;

  if myCursorResult%ROWCOUNT > 1 then raise TOO_MANY_ROWS;

  else if myCursorResult%ROWCOUNT = 0 then raise NO_DATA_FOUND;

  end if;

  end if;

  exception

    when TOO_MANY_ROWS then raise_application_error(-20000, 'base corrompue');

    when NO_DATA_FOUND then raise_application_error(-20001, 'pas de résultats');

end getClientFromAuthentification;`
```

---

I tested it in oracle sqldevelopper and it works fine :

---

```
`set serveroutput on;

declare

myCursor sys_refcursor;

begin

  dbms_output.enable;

  getclientfromauthentification(myCursor, 'durant.jean', 'durant.jean1234');

  dbms_output.put_line('cursor = ' || myCursor%ROWCOUNT);

end;`
```

---

cursor = 1 (it found it :=))

Now I try to use this procedure on java side with hybernate.

The mapping :

---

```
`<hibernate-mapping>

  <class name="model.entity.Client">

    <id name="num_client" type="int" />

    <property name="num_compte_epargne" type="string" />

    <property name="num_compte_courant" type="string" />

    <property name="nom" type="string" />

    <property name="prenom" type="string" />

    <property name="adresse" type="string" />

  </class>

  <sql-query name="getClientFromAuthentification_SP" callable="true">

    <return alias="client" class="model.entity.Client" >

        <return-property name="num_client" column="NUM_CLIENT"/>

        <return-property name="num_compte_epargne" column="NUM_COMPTE_EPARGNE"/>

        <return-property name="num_compte_courant" column="NUM_COMPTE_CLIENT"/>

        <return-property name="nom" column="NOM_CLIENT"/>

        <return-property name="prenom" column="PRENOM_CLIENT"/>

        <return-property name="adresse" column="ADRESSE_CLIENT"/>

    </return>

    { call getClientFromAuthentification(?, :login, :mdp) }

  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>`
```

---

When I use it :

---

`

```
ArrayList<Client> clients;

 Query q = session.getNamedQuery("getClientFromAuthentification_SP");

 q.setString("login", "durant.jean");

 q.setString("mdp", "durant.jean1234");


 clients = (ArrayList<Client>) q.list();`
```

I have no errors but Unfortunatly the list is empty...

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure, use `%NOTFOUND` instead of `%ROWCOUNT`:

- You should use %rowcount only with
  implicit cursors that do
  insert/update/delete.
- You should use %notfound with SELECTs
  to see if they return data or not. [E.g.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Cursor/ExitWhenCursorNOTFOUND.htm)

edit: the whole proc added to the answer

```
create or replace procedure getClientFromAuthentification(myCursorResult out sys_refcursor, login in VARCHAR2, pwd in VARCHAR2) as
num_client NUMBER(6);
compte_epargne VARCHAR2(50);
compte_courant VARCHAR2(50);
nom VARCHAR2(50);
prenom VARCHAR2(50);
adresse VARCHAR2(100);
begin
  open myCursorResult for
    select client.num_client, client.num_compte_epargne, client.num_compte_courant, 
client.nom_client, client.prenom_client, client.adresse_client
    from client 
    where client.login_client = login and client.mdp_client = pwd;
  fetch myCursorResult into num_client, compte_epargne, compte_courant, nom, prenom, adresse;
  if myCursorResult%NOTFOUND then 
    raise NO_DATA_FOUND;
  end if;
exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then raise_application_error(-20001, 'pas de résultats');
end getClientFromAuthentification;
```

Regarding the whole design:

- Why do you return something wrapped in a
  cursor having exactly one row?
- Why not have these as out parameter:

  `num_client, compte_epargne, compte_courant, nom, prenom, adresse`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but let's imagine that I want to use a cursor. How would it work ?

Comment: That's the first part of my answer! replace `%ROWCOUNT` with `%NOTFOUND`. Let me help you with that, I add it to my answer

Comment: How do you raise 'TWO_MANY-ROWS' exception with NOTFOUND.

Comment: and just by changing rowcount by notfound, hibernate will be able to map the cursor in my list of objects ?

Comment: If you want to raise 'TWO_MANY-ROWS', you can do it by either trying to fetch one more row from the cursor -- you raise 'TWO_MANY-ROWS' if the second fetch attempt was successful (`if not myCursorResult%NOTFOUND then`)

Comment: I suppose Hibernate has already been able to map the cursor. When you asked for help, you said your problem was the list was empty! I figured this may be related with your wrong usage of the cursor in your stored procedure, that's what I'm trying to help you with.